# Filter DataTables with multiple custom toggle buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm attempting to get button filters to work similar to how the API page here works: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ but with individual rows as opposed to sections.

For example:

1. Click a button "heavy", rows that include the string "heavy" in a specific column are shown.
2. Clicked another button "light", rows that include "heavy" AND "light" are shown.
3. Clicked "light" again, only "heavy" rows are shown again.
4. Clicked "medium" button, rows "heavy" and "medium" are shown.

I've been scouring their documentation and the questions here but am unable to find a solution.

The following is where I keep reducing my code down to after each failed attempt. This code brings up the rows I want for that particular button, however if I click another button, it resets search and does not add the results to it.

```
$('.filter-button').each(function() {$(this).click(function() {
    program = $(this).text();
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-program') == program;
       }
    );
    table.draw();
});
```

Comment: Try google "*datatables custom filtering*" ...

Comment: I have already been over this documentation multiple times with no success for my particular situation. The documentation you are referring to here https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html very briefly goes over simple filtering rules, but nothing in regards to toggling, or appending/removing rows. I am hoping someone has an example similar to the functionality on their own site.